# meteor based websites can't be accessible from corporate networks

Tags: meteor

I built 2 apps based on meteor for big clients - MAN and BMW Denmark.  Unfortunately both can't see apps (just white screen in browsers) from own internal networks. I able to see it, my partners able to see it, issue somehow happened only from their[bmw and man] networks. I think somehow it's related to their firewalls or any kind of security settings/services, but it's impossible to get any info from their tech. department. What kind of issues could be the reason of this scenario? I'm 100% sure it's related to meteor only, 'coz old-school solutions (Django-based) works fine from same domain. And it's not related to exact apps 'coz 'em works on any another browser outside of corporate networks.

Comment: Sounds like javascript is disabled to me.

Comment: I agree, be sure to enable javascript in browser

Comment: Nope, any other website works fine (with JS, cookies and so on).

Comment: Maybe because of websockets ?

Comment: Enable SSL, see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Are they using IE8, like many big companies still do? The white screen sounds like a past iron-router bug: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/1037.

Comment: Have you tried running a reduction case, a very simple "Hello World" meteor app from the same domain? Are you able to see other meteor apps elsewhere on the internet from within the network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not the port as suggested, the IT group may have restrictions in place, like an aggressive web filter or strict site whitelisting. Speaking from my team's experience inside a large corporation, we even have trouble building our apps behind the firewall because of the package checks with every server refresh. We get the same thing with NPM and bower.

Answer (score 0):

What do see happening if you run Fiddler? Blank screens can be due to a bad request.

We had a situation similar to yours and the issue was related to the F5 load balancing appliance stripping HTTP headers and the corporate network using a proxy server. The header we lost was the X-Forwaded-for causing issues when going through the corporate proxy server. We had to troubleshoot with their IT to resolve it.

Compare the Fiddler trace from outside the corporate network with one from within the corporate network.

If it works outside the corporate network, the issue is probably something like I'm describing above.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely defaulting the websocket port to something other than 80/443. A lot of corporate firewalls block traffic on ports other than 80 & 443.